# Resources not found in a multilanguage WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a C# WPF application that needs a multi-language solution.

To achieve that I created four files under Properties folder:

Resources.resx

Resources.en.resx

Resources.fr.resx

Resources.es.resx

Each file has MyApp.Language as Namespace of the custom tool.
In  `Mainwindow.xaml` I added:

```
<Window ...
 xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:MyApp.Language" 
...
```

I want to change the content of a label, so I (tried to) inserted:

```
<Label Margin="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{x:Static lang:Partenza}" />
```

The editor reports the error: The member 'lang:Partenza' is not valid.
When I wrote the term `lang:` any other suggestions are not shown, so I guess it is not recognized.
The access modifier of the resources items is 'Public'.

Where am I wrong??

PS: I changed the resource files with 'ResX Manager', so I guess they are correctly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong in the way you are referencing the resource.

You are trying to reference the resource as lang:Partenza, but you should be referencing it as MyApp.Language:Partenza.

The lang prefix is not a valid prefix for a resource. You can only use the namespace of the resource as the prefix.

So, your XAML should look like this:

```
<Label Margin="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{x:Static MyApp.Language:Partenza}" />
```

**[EDIT]**

The reason for this is that the xmlns:lang attribute is not defined in your XAML file. This attribute tells the XAML parser that the lang prefix is used to reference resources from the MyApp.Language namespace.

To fix this error, you need to add the xmlns:lang attribute to your XAML file. The value of the attribute should be the namespace of the resource file that contains the resource that you want to reference.

In your case, the namespace of the resource file is MyApp.Language. So, your XAML file should look like this:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:MyApp.Language"
 ...>
...
</Window>
```

[EDIT 2]

You might be missing the correct syntax to access the resources from your localized files. Instead of using {x:Static lang:Partenza}, you should use {x:Static lang:Resources.Partenza} to access the localized resource value. Here’s the corrected code snippet:

```
<Label Margin="0" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Content="{x:Static lang:Resources.Partenza}" />
```

Make sure that the Partenza resource key exists in all of your Resources.resx, Resources.en.resx, Resources.fr.resx, and Resources.es.resx files, as it seems you’re trying to access it through the default namespace MyApp.Language.

Hope this time will solve.

Comment: Not working. The reference to MyApp.Language is not suggested and, anyway, not valid, error.

Comment: The row containing xmlns:lang is present in the Window tag, see the original message

Answer (score 1):

if you have Resources.resx, then you should also have Resources.Designer.cs file.

Available resources will be accessible via static properties of the class generated in the Designer.

xmlns declaration should match the namespace in the Designer file.

after that use `{x:Static}` with xmlns + class name + resource property, e.g.:

```
Content="{x:Static lang:Resources.Partenza}"
```

Comment: The Resource.Designer.cs file is present but when I write 'lang:'  'Settings' is the only suggested item.

Comment: I renamed the namespace as 'LanguageMgr' just to avoid any confusion. If I enter the C# code ```LanguageMgr.Resources.PregoSelezionareLaDestinazione``` this is ok. The problem is only in the xaml syntax.

Comment: I wrote/forced the xaml code ```Content="{x:Static lang:Resources.Prenota}"```, even if not suggested and this is accepted.  Now if I change the language by  code with ```Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");``` the labels are not updated. I'm wondering if this is the correct way (since the x:Static declaration ..): if I Debug.Write() the string ```LanguageMgr.Resources.PregoSelezionareLaDestinazione``` is translated.

Comment: "Now if I change the language by code with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en"); the labels are not updated" - that is expected, there is no way to update them if {x:Static} is used. changing texts in runtime is an advanced scenario and requires differnet approach

Comment: Is the required approach by xaml files instead of resx files?

Comment: @SteMMo, it is possible to implement another markup extension (as a replacement for x:static) which will use translation from resx file